# Create a column with the reutrn result of a function in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to create a column with a random integer that is between 1 and the length of the unique values of a different column.

In other words it is a way in which to randomly re-assign the category of each row from a sample of all the unique values that column could possibly be.

Here is what I have. Unfortunatly, It returns exactly what I put in.

```
randomBinAssigner <- function(testingDT) {
  levelsInCat <- levels(testingDT$randomCat)
  testingDT[, randomCatKey := sample(1:length(levelsInCat), 1, replace = T)]
  testingDT[, randomCat := levelsInCat[randomCatKey]]
  testingDT[, randomCatKey := NULL]
  return(testingDT)
}
```

Comment: I'm not a data.table expert, but it seems suspicious that you first create the column `randomCatKey` with the sample values and two lines afterwards set `randomCatKey` to `NULL` which, I believe, will basically delete the column again. What if you remove that? (just a shot in the dark.. )

Comment: I was creating and removing the column and using it in the time between. I would make the code more terse but for the questions sake I thought it would make the question more clear.

Comment: Okay, understood. By the way, I think you could  eliminate that extra step and directly use something like `sample(levelsInCat, 1, T)` or even remove the step before and write `sample(levels(testingDT$randomCat), 1, T)`

Comment: Good call. I'm relatively new to R. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No reproducible example in OP with clear desired output, but my guess is you're simply missing a "by":

```
testingDT[, randomCatKey := sample(length(levelsInCat), 1, T), by = randomCat]
```